# What if we know exact position of electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electrons, atoms, orbitals

I know many scientist gives many theory to explain structure of atom and that's Quantum mechanics explained very well. Even Schrondiger eq. to get idea where electron more probable is around a nucleus give just a probability. I am beginner so plz.. guide me why there is so rat race behind the position of electron ? I definitely want to know why, if someone know exact position then what will be consequences then ?

Comment: How can you obtain the exact position of an electron?  It is too small to see with photons.  Bouncing another electron off of it will disturb the thing that you are trying to measure.  It's probably impossible to get the data that you are assuming.

Comment: An electron is a quantum of energy. Energy doesn't have a position. It never had a position in classical mechanics, either.

Answer (score 3):

Position and momentum are conjugate quantities.  In QM that implies that if position is exactly determined, momentum is completely indeterminate.  That is, the momentum could be literally anything: any direction, any value.

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore details like phase, the wavefunction of an electron "in one place" is a Dirac delta function which can be represented as the limit as N goes to infinity of
$$ \delta_N(x)= \dfrac{1}{\pi} \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \cos nx +\dfrac{1}{2} \right) \label{2.1.14} $$
Since this sort of shape can only be created with a fairly even mix of frequencies going to infinity and electron velocity is proportional to frequency, the average expected velocity also goes to infinity.

[This site](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Quantum_Mechanics/Book%3A_Quantum_Mechanics_(Fowler)/02%3A_Some_Essential_Math/2.01%3A_Fourier_Series_and_Integrals%2C_the_Dirac_Function) 
has a nice picture of what it looks like after adding in the first 20 frequencies:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the electron is in an exact position:

$$ \psi(\vec r) \propto \delta(r)\delta(\theta)\delta(\phi) $$

then, if we just look at the angular momentum quantum numbers:

$$c_{lm} =\langle l m|\psi|l m\rangle \propto \iint_{\Omega} \bar Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)\delta(\theta)\delta(\phi)Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)\sin\theta d\theta d\phi $$

$$c_{lm}= \iint_{\Omega}\delta(\theta)\delta(\phi)||Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)||^2 \sin\theta d\theta d\phi \ne 0$$

meaning it is, in general, a linear combination of all orbital angular momenta and all magnetic quantum numbers.

Likewise, the $\delta(r)$ will have a non-zero projection onto *all* the principle quantum numbers, and the unbound states as well.

In theory, you can talk about this state, but it is a mess as a far describing it with quantum numbers is concerned.

In practice, it is just not "a thing" one needs to consider.